# Jquery Banner Slider is not working in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have add Banner Slider in My Magento Website on Homepage .  It is working perfectly in all browsers Except Internet Explorer.

So,Please Suggest any idea.

Comment: You need to give us more than this. Post your code here on Stackoverflow. Also consider posting a jsfiddle / post a link to your site.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Jquery Slider is not working in IE 7 and IE 8.

Then Following code you have to apply.

getSkinUrl(); ?>css/yourCSS" type="text/css" />

```
        <!--[if IE]>
             <style type="text/css">
                 .timer { display: none !important; }
                 div.caption { background:transparent; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);zoom: 1; }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
             jQuery(window).load(function() {
             jQuery('#featured').orbit();
        });
    </script>
```